# How to insert primary key when import text file with ssis

Tags: ssis, primary-key

I am a new guy in SSIS. Today, I have a problem. When I import data in text file to table by SSIS package, it show an error "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'CustomerID', table 'Customer'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails". The column CustomerID is primary key in table. I want to generate primary key. Can anyone help me. Thank you so much.

Comment: ...and what does your primary key contain?

Answer (score 0):

Well the error is pretty obvious. No `NULL`s in the primary key. Usually the method used to generate a primary key is to declare `CustomerID` as an `IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY` column which will auto-populate the column with `UNIQUE` values as and when you `INSERT` a record.

For more information on `IDENTITY` columns - [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx)

Note that if you employ this, you **MUST NOT** insert any value for the column `CustomerID` from your text file.

Please note that in your question you have mentioned

> I want to generate primary key.

Make sure any of your other data/tables do not currently use the column `CustomerID`. If so, then you need to retain the same `CustomerID`s or `UPDATE` the referencing columns in order to make sure they hold the new `CustomerID`s.

Comment: My pleasure, if this was the answer you were looking for please click the green tick button :)